# Как получить значение из другого потока C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Основная форма виснет при выполнении цикла. Я понимаю что нужно вынести его в отдельный поток. Вот сделано. Теперь ругается компилятор на невозможность получения данных richTextBox1 из другого потока. Как их получить конкретно в моём случае? Знаю что надо выносить всё это дело в отдельный класс вроде, но не могу понять как. Куда вставлять его, как вызывать потом.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (j < i)
                {
                    j++;
                    subj.SendKeys(richTextBox1.Text);
                    subj.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
                    Thread.Sleep(st);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Попробуйте `richTextBox1.Invoke((Action)(() => subj.SendKeys(richTextBox1.Text)));`

Answer (score 4):

Элементы WinForms в C# запрещают обращения из других потоков. Для того, чтобы обращаться к ним из других потоков, необходимо воспользоваться методом [Control.Invoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netcore-3.1). В качестве параметра он принимает делегат, который будет вызван в том потоке, где этот элемент был создан:

> Метод Invoke выполняет поиск по родительской цепочке элемента управления до тех пор, пока не найдет элемент управления или форму, которая имеет оконный обработчик, если его базовый маркер окна текущего элемента управления еще не существует. Если не удается найти соответствующий обработчик, метод Invoke вызовет исключение. Исключения, возникающие во время вызова, передаются обратно вызывающему объекту.

В вашем случае вместо

```
subj.SendKeys(richTextBox1.Text);
```

Вы нуждаетесь в

```
richTextBox1.Invoke((Action)(() => subj.SendKeys(richTextBox1.Text)));
```

Это должно работать

Comment: Отличный ответ! я бы, на месте автора вопроса, "принял" его!